# Plot and facet a map in R

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, facet, ggmap

main data frame

```
data.frame(lat = c(38.6938, 38.4262, 32.7607, 37.083, 39.4619, 41.0042),
                 lon = c(-9.20587, -8.90007, -16.9595, -8.90918, -8.38391, -7.9699),
                 views = c(13565, 27020, 74420, 18550, 73253, 14615),
                 challenge = c("SPOT CIDADE", "SPOT NATUREZA I",
                               "SPOT NATUREZA II", "SPOT ROMANCE",
                               "SPOT PATRIMONIO", "SPOT GASTRONOMIA"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I am trying to plot a map, for print, and the result would be a map for each challenge and the points changing their size based on the views each video has.

So far, my code brings all points in the same map - i'm having issues with the faceting and changing the size of the points.

When I change the variable in the aesthetics the points get huge.

The zoom levels are either too close or too far.

The code i'm using is below. 
every example I see is either too far from want I need, or it just don't 
work.

Am I doing it right, or this needs another approach?

Thanks!

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

lon <- as.numeric(new$lon)
lat <- as.numeric(new$lat)


spots_df <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon, lat))

mapa_spots <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(spots_df$lon), lat = mean(spots_df$lat)), zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain", scale = 2)

plot_spots <- ggmap(mapa_spots) +
  geom_point(data = spots_df, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = "red", alpha = 0.8), size = 2, shape = 21) +
  guides(fill=FALSE, alpha=FALSE, size=FALSE)

plot_spots
```

The result I get from this code:

[image: plot_spots]

Comment: Please, share the output of `dput(spots_df)`. It would be easier to help you.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you intend this to look like.

Comment: I am sorry. Each dot represents a video and I would like to have the dots changing their size based on the views. And I would like to have each challenge in a separate map.

Comment: I replaced your image with a reproducible code. In the future, please do not post your data as an image again. Always provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called `dt`, here is a plot with [ggmap](/questions/tagged/ggmap) and [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2). The key is to use `base_layer` argument with `ggplot(dt, aes(...))` so that you can further add other `geom` just like a `ggplot` call. You mentioned that you want each challenge in a separate map in your comment. I think `facet_wrap` is probably what you are looking for.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)

mapa_spots <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(dt$lon), 
                                   lat = mean(dt$lat)), 
                      zoom = 6, maptype = "terrain", scale = 2)

ggmap(mapa_spots, base_layer = ggplot(dt, aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = views))) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~challenge, ncol = 3)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
dt <- data.frame(lat = c(38.6938, 38.4262, 32.7607, 37.083, 39.4619, 41.0042),
                 lon = c(-9.20587, -8.90007, -16.9595, -8.90918, -8.38391, -7.9699),
                 views = c(13565, 27020, 74420, 18550, 73253, 14615),
                 challenge = c("SPOT CIDADE", "SPOT NATUREZA I",
                               "SPOT NATUREZA II", "SPOT ROMANCE",
                               "SPOT PATRIMONIO", "SPOT GASTRONOMIA"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes, that is it! The {base_layer} argument is a new tip for me. Thank you!